# Hardy's Theorem via Hadamard's three circles theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Does somebody know a proof for Hardy's Theorem? That is if $f$ is a complex analytic function from the open ball of radius $R$ centered at the origin, then the function
$$I(r)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|\,{\rm d}\theta$$
is strictly increasing and log convex as a function of $\log(r)$ (I guess for all $r\in[r_1,r_2]$ where $0<r_1<r_2<R$).
Here is what I tried... For a fixed $r$ one defines $\varphi(\theta)=\frac{|f(re^{i\theta})|}{f(re^{i\theta})}$ and
$$F(z)=\int_0^{2\pi}f(ze^{i\theta})\varphi(\theta)d\theta$$
for all $z$ in the annulus $r_1\leq|z|\leq r_2$. Let $M(\rho)=\sup_{|z|=\rho}|F(z)|$, so that $M(\rho)\leq I(\rho)$ for all $\rho\in [r_1,r_2]$, with equality for $\rho=r$. As $F$ is analytic, by Hadamard's three circle theorem we get that $\log M(\rho)$ is a convex function of $\log\rho$. This in turn implies that the same holds true for $I(\rho)$ i.e.
$$\log I(r)\leq\frac{\log r_2-\log r}{\log r_2-\log r_1}\log I(r_1)+\frac{\log r-\log r_1}{\log r_2-\log r_1}\log I(r_2)$$
Now, bringing $r_1\rightarrow 0$ we get $\log I(r)\leq\log I(r_2)$ which implies that $I(r)$ is a nondecreasing function.
However I am quite clueless about how to prove that the inequality is strict. Any ideas?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy's_theorem which references Conway

Comment: Conway doesn't contain a proof of the theorem, it is given as an exercise

Comment: Have you attempted it then? Even more, have you just tried searching online? Surely googling "Hardy's Theorem Proof" should yield at least one such proof.

Comment: I attempted it but with no success... and googling it yields proofs of more general versions which require more advanced machinery, while I think that this one can be proven using Hadamard's 3 circle theorem only.

Comment: @pozio look at page 142 in [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=j3D0BwAAQBAJ) for hints on how to solve the problem.